# Simple function is not working in Chrome 57.0.2977.98 (64bit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple function that works perfectly in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe the same function can be written in some other ways?

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#menumore", function() {
    $("#menumore span").addClass("black")
})

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#menumore", function() {
    $("#menumore span").removeClass("black")
})
```

```css
#menumore{font-family:Arial; font-size:60px;corsor:pointer;}
.white{opacity:0;transition:opacity .2s cubic-bezier(0.77,0,0.175,1)}
.black{opacity:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=menumore>M<span class=white>ENU</span></div>
```

Comment: works for me in chrome

Comment: I'd suggest using CSS for this

Comment: what error you get in console?

Comment: Works fine also in Opera, which is webkit based.

Comment: I get no error it just doesn't show the .shite class as it should.
@Rajesh I would love to hear more :)

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Your code seems to be working fine, so it may be an unrelated issue that is affecting this code.

Comment: There are no errors in Console

Comment: make sure browser not block the script file.

Comment: _webkit based_ not an issue. OP said it is not working in Chrome. He also said works fine in Safari, which is also Webkit based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, you should try using CSS.

```css
#menumore {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 60px;
  corsor: pointer;
}

.white {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1)
}

#menumore:hover .white {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div id=menumore>M<span class=white>ENU</span></div>
```